# Reading Excel file into Tableau skipping first few rows

Tags: tableau-api, import-from-excel

I have a Tableau chart reading from a shared Excel file. Now the Excel file owner has added a few header lines into the file that causes Tableau to not recognise the column headers. I have no control on the Excel (i.e. cannot change the content), and my chart is supposed to read from that file "live" (i.e. I can't maintain a separate "cleaned" copy).

Is there a way to make Tableau skip the first few rows when reading from Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 9 is due to ship soon, and has features to help cases like this.

Comment: Not really. Tableau offers to do it automatically, but if it doesn't get it right you're out of luck.

Comment: If Tableau's data interpreter can't automatically detect where your table starts, you can also see if you define a named range in Excel to explicitly make the table boundaries. Tableau can see named ranges.